# JMeter - Samplers are not recorded under Recording Controller

Tags: jmeter

[image]

Responses got captured in `View Results in Table`, but samplers are not recorded under `Recording Controller`

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is just move the Recording Controller to "Test Plan" section and make it a child of the "Thread Group".

By the way, you can get a "good" recording configuration in a couple of clicks using [JMeter's Templates Feature](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature), just choose `File -> Templates -> Recording -> Create` from JMeter's Main Menu and the relevant test elements will appear automatically.

[image: JMeter Recording Template]

Remember that for [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) originated from the Template default proxy port is **8888**